# How to access to header variables from component?

Tags: spring-boot

Have a banner.txt with multi variables, for example `${application.formatted-version}`. Howto access to same variables but from a java component?

I try use `@Value` like as:

```
@Value("${application.formatted-version}")
private String applicationVersion;
```

But the compiler says:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MainComponent': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'application.formatted-version' in value "${application.formatted-version}"
```

Comment: spring only supports `json`, `properties`, or `yml` files

Answer (score 0):

More details needed for your problem. In Spring if you want to get access to your variable from configuration file you need to move this variable to application.properties, there you have to set its value and then you'll be able to get access to it from Component using @Value annotation.
Details on how to do this in Spring Boot under https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html